# Combining the coalescence more than once?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

Is there anything in C# that would allow you to do something such as

```
string str = nullval1 ?? nullval2 ?? nullval3 ?? "Hi";
```

and it would go left to right picking the first one that is not null?

If this operator doesnt do this, is there a possible alternative to provide similar function with minimal code?

Comment: that would have taken just a minute to try out..

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Coding without any way to build atm, so im trying to check my syntax before i do this a bunch of times.

Comment: In case you find yourself coding without a compiler, but still have Internet access, do yourself a favor and give [ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/) a try. For example, here's the sample code from Jon Skeet's answer: http://www.ideone.com/qOvPI

Comment: @Cody Gray: thankyou for the reference, i definitely bookmarked that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works absolutely fine as-is. Sample code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = null;
        string y = "y";
        string z = "z";

        Console.WriteLine(x ?? y ?? z); // Prints "y"
    }
}
```

Comment: really? thats interesting, ive never seen any examples of this.. anywhere.

Comment: @Tommy: There's always your friendly neighborhood compiler! :D

Comment: @BoltClock: Coding without any way to build atm, so im trying to check my syntax before i do this a bunch of times.

Comment: @Tommy, section 7.12 of the C# language specification discusses this behavior the `??` operator. It is right associative, such that `a ?? b ?? c` evaluates to `a ?? (b ?? c)`, so `a` is evaluated first, then the right expression `b ?? c`, which evaluates `b`. The specification goes on to say "In general terms, an expression of the form E1 ?? E2 ?? ... ?? EN returns the first of the operands that is non-null, or null if all operands are null"